# При реализации Netty сервера, клиент не получает строку

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, netty

не получается отправить с сервера Netty обычную строку, хотя эхо-тест получается отправить клиенту. Сервер реализовал как в документации по Netty:

```
public class NettyServer2 {

private int port;

public NettyServer2(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); // (1)
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(
                                new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                                new DiscardServerHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 8080;
    new NettyServer2(port).run();
}
```

}

Handler при котором получается отправить клиенту эхо тест, т.е. "[сообщение отправленное на сервер]"

```
    @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.write(msg);
    ctx.flush(); 
}
```

При таком Handler клиент ничего не получает

```
    @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(
            Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("OK".getBytes()));
}
```

Хотя если сделать так, то клиент получает: "ОК[сообщение отправленное на сервер]"

```
    @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(
            Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("OK".getBytes()));
    ctx.write(msg);
    ctx.flush();
}
```

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `flush` не происходит, нужно добавить "\r\n", возможно будет достаточно "\n" однако такой вариант не проверял.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(
            Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("OK\r\n".getBytes()));
}
```

Когда-то гуглил похожую проблему, но объяснения не нашёл.

Comment: Спасибо, работает и с "\r\n" и с "\n". Видимо для flush символ перевода строки обязателен.